# Discord.py Reaction Roles can't remove roles

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey the Reaction role add works but i can't remove the roles
everytime i click the reaction this error pops up:

File "main.py", line 165, in on_raw_reaction_remove
await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

My Code:

````
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild: discord.Guild = client.get_guild(815637550550089739)
    if payload.message_id == 872659703598047232:
        if payload.emoji.name == 'Hypixel':
            role: discord.Role = guild.get_role(872606322653286400)
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
    if payload.message_id == 872659703598047232:
        if payload.emoji.name == 'Skyblock':
            role: discord.Role = guild.get_role(872606320379953193)
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason behind this is `payload.member` is `None` when using `on_raw_reaction_remove`.
This is actually because discord does not send this data, so discord.py has it as `None`.
Source-https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5871

To work around this, you get the guild object in question, then grab the member object from the guild.
The payload does not have the guild object either, so we have to get that as well.

What I did is I actually created the member object and tacked it onto the payload manually in the case of `on_raw_reaction_remove`.
This way both `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove` have the same payload for my final processing.

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):    
  guild = self.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  #Self here is Client/Bot
  member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
  payload.member = member
  await reaction_role(payload, remove=True)
```

Furthermore, this requires the privileged members intent. To enable it, log back into the developer portal and look for the privileged intents > member intent, then tick the slider to on.

```
intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
```

The intent needs to be passed to the client, or bot wrapper if using the bot extension.

```
commands.Bot.__init__(self, <...>, intents=intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member
`payload.member` is only available when **adding** an reaction, otherwise it's value will be `None`.
You should be using `on_raw_reaction_add`.

Comment: Well as well as you have `discord.Member` object for that user(and bot has required permission), you can remove the role from that user.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "the code", but just replace `on_raw_reaction_remove` with `on_raw_reaction_add`.  
Also I recommend you joining official discord.py [discord](https://discord.gg/dpy).  
It's ran by the author of discord.py himself, and really easy to get help from experienced users(and me!).